# Vim is in read-only mode

Tags: vimrc, insert-mode, normal-mode

I'm using vim for scripting and configs and noticed that I sometimes forget to open file with `sudo` and therefore when I made some editings I got the error:

```
E45: 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override)
```

So I have to exit and make all the edits I just made for scratch. This is very annoying. Is there a way to approach it? Maybe I can switch from readonly mode without exiting vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [write with sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600783/how-does-the-vim-write-with-sudo-trick-work) trick:

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

See also @ChristianBrabandt's [SudoEdit plugin](http://github.com/chrisbra/SudoEdit.vim/) which also works on Windows and supports undofiles.

Answer (score 1):

you could reset the readonly option with `:set noro`

But the underlying problem in your case is access-right.
As a normal user you (and vim) cannot write a root-file.

To save your changes with root-permission you can try :

`:w !sudo tee % > /dev/null`